# How can I change the MAC address of hosted network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-8.1, mac-address

I am on a MAC-filterd network. I have a pc and a laptop.  I started a hosted network on my laptop. The Laptop has Windows 8.

I set up a hosted network on this laptop to connect a smartphone.

So the question is now: can I connect a phone to this hosted network in such a way that it has internet access?

I thought it would be enough to turn off the PC and change the MAC address of the hosted network to that one of the PC. Is that true? If yes, how can I achieve that?

Comment: Why can't you just add the phone's MAC address to the list of allowed addresses.

Comment: Because I have no access to this list.

Comment: This question is unclear/needs more detail. Also, machines have MAC addresses, not networks.

Comment: If you cannot add the phone to the list of devices allowed to connect to the network then you can connect to the network on the phone.  You could in theory use a secondary wireless device adapter and create a virtual access point and connect to that network.

Comment: @Ramhound: I want to have internet access on the phone via laptop. I don't want to use my phones cellular data connection.

Comment: What I describe would do what you want...

Comment: Okay. Could you then give me please a more detailed answer? How can I "connect the network on the phone"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable internet connection sharing on your laptop (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/set-internet-connection-sharing#1TC=windows-7). Then you should see "sharing" tab for each network adapter. Lets say the adapter that has internet connection is "Local LAN". Open its properties. Go to sharing tab. Enable sharing. Then in the list box of available network connections, you need to pick the one corresponding to hosted network. Now the connections from wifi clients of hosted network go through that of "Local LAN".

One caveat with clients that connect over wifi to hosted network is that they don't inherit the dns server addresses from your laptop. On the client (iPhone or some other laptop), you need to go to ipv4 settings and set dns server correctly. Usually I add 8.8.8.8 which is widely known dns server backed by Google. If you are doing this under corporate network, find dns server from "ipconfig /all" for "Local LAN" adapter and use that dns server on the clients. Corporate networks tend to have proxy servers that need user id and password for web access. Then you will have to configure those things on your iPhone and Android phone for web access to internet work correctly.